# more efficient query for pulling out of history

Tags: sql, db2

This query already works, but I'm getting reports of "Resource Limit Exceeded" which scares me.

I have three tables: mainTable, sideTable, and leftJoin.

mainTable is associated to two employee numbers, because they can work by themselves or in a pair of two.

sideTable has the Employee Name.

LeftJoin has the Employee Activity, which is a big table of activities where I have to get the latest status.

I don't know if this is a good query or not, but it calls the sideTable twice and calls the LeftJoin twice.

This query is 12 seconds.

```
WITH cteTbl AS (
    SELECT
         EmployeeID
         ,MAX(TIMESTAMP(StampDate, StampTime)) AS cteMaxTime
    FROM
         /**/ getMaxDateTime
    GROUP BY EmployeeID
)
SELECT
    /* stuff */
    ,sideTable1.EmployeeName1
    ,sideTable2.EmployeeName2
    ,leftJoinA.EmployeeStatus 
    ,leftJoinB.EmployeeStatus 


FROM 
    /**/ mainTable

LEFT JOIN /**/ sideTable1
    ON mainTable.employeeNumber = sideTable1.employeeNumber

LEFT JOIN /**/ sideTable2
    ON mainTable.employeeNumber = sideTable2.employeeNumber

    /*tons of left joins*/


LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT      leftJoinA.EmployeeNumber, leftJoinA.EmployeeStatus 
    FROM        /**/ leftJoinA
    INNER JOIN  cteTbl
        ON leftjoinA.EmployeeNumber = cteTbl.EmployeeNumber
            AND TIMESTAMP(leftjoinA.StampDate,leftjoinA.StampTime) = cteTbl.cteMaxTime
) innerStampData1
    ON sideTable1.EmployeeNumber1 = innerStampData1.EmployeeNumber


LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT      leftJoinB.EmployeeNumber, leftJoinB.EmployeeStatus 
    FROM        /**/ leftJoinB
    INNER JOIN  cteTbl
        ON leftjoinB.EmployeeNumber = cteTbl.EmployeeNumber
            AND TIMESTAMP(leftjoinB.StampDate,leftjoinB.StampTime) = cteTbl.cteMaxTime
) innerStampData2
    ON sideTable2.EmployeeNumber2 = innerStampData2.EmployeeNumber

WHERE
    /**/

GROUP BY 
    /**/

ORDER BY
    /**/
```

If I do this, the query is seven seconds but the results are duplicated for every team.

```
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT      leftJoinA.EmployeeNumber, leftJoinA.EmployeeStatus 
    FROM        /**/ leftJoinA
    INNER JOIN  cteTbl
        ON leftjoinA.EmployeeNumber = cteTbl.EmployeeNumber
            AND TIMESTAMP(leftjoinA.StampDate,leftjoinA.StampTime) = cteTbl.cteMaxTime
) innerStampData1
    ON sideTable.EmployeeNumber1 = innerStampData1.EmployeeNumber OR sideTable2.EmployeeNumber = innerStampData2.EmployeeNumber
```

Comment: what indexes you have on this tables?

Comment: it is hard to find better query, if you write only part of sql, don't write definitions of tables and don't write example data...

Answer (score 0):

try this query:

```
WITH 
  cteTbl AS (
    SELECT EmployeeID
    , MAX(TIMESTAMP(StampDate, StampTime)) AS cteMaxTime
    FROM /**/ getMaxDateTime
    GROUP BY EmployeeID)
SELECT
/* stuff */
  sideTable1.EmployeeName1
, sideTable2.EmployeeName2
, innerStampData1.EmployeeStatus 
, innerStampData2.EmployeeStatus 
FROM /**/ mainTable
LEFT JOIN /**/ sideTable1
  ON mainTable.employeeNumber = sideTable1.employeeNumber
LEFT JOIN /**/ sideTable2
  ON mainTable.employeeNumber = sideTable2.employeeNumber
  /*tons of left joins*/
LEFT JOIN ( 
  SELECT EmployeeNumber
  , EmployeeStatus 
  FROM /**/ leftJoinA
  WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM cteTbl 
    WHERE leftjoinA.EmployeeNumber = cteTbl.EmployeeNumber
    AND TIMESTAMP(leftjoinA.StampDate,leftjoinA.StampTime) = cteTbl.cteMaxTime)
)  innerStampData1
  ON (sideTable1.EmployeeNumber1 = innerStampData1.EmployeeNumber 
    OR sideTable2.EmployeeNumber2 = innerStampData2.EmployeeNumber)

WHERE
    /**/
GROUP BY 
    /**/
ORDER BY
    /**/
```